# Joomla 403 Forbidden when trying to access php file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, joomla

I have a Joomla site. I've created a subfolder with a landing page.
This landing page was coded in HTML + CSS. This works perfectly but now I have added a little PHP plugin to manage MailChimp subscribers. But when I try to access to the php file, the server throws the following 403 error:

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access http://www.domain.es/folder/sub-folder/server.php

I have changed the .htaccess file to allow PHP files the following way (but it doesn't work):

```
<FilesMatch *.php$>
 Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the actual permissions of the file and it's parent directories?

Comment: You know you shouldn't have permissions set to 777.

Comment: As for the issue itself, you might have to specifically allow access to that php file in htaccess.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the .htaccess altogether and see if that helps? Also, have you checked the ModSecurity log on your server? The issue might be caused by ModSecurity.

Comment: Are you passing anything into your sub-folder's php file?
There are anti-exploit catchers in Joomla's .htaccess file that rewrite some atypical url params to a 403.  Perhaps you're getting caught by one of these.

Comment: you can't access a file outside Joomla's framework via your Joomla site URL. To be able to access that file, you will have to either access that file via some module as IFRAME or adding the Joomla framework initialization script to the very beginning of the file.

Comment: the script is:
`define('_JEXEC', 1);
if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/defines.php'))  
{  
include_once __DIR__ . '/defines.php';  
}  
if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) 
{  
define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);  
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';  
}  
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';  
JDEBUG ? JProfiler::getInstance('Application')->setStart($startTime, $startMem)->mark('afterLoad') : null;  
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');  
$app->execute();`
But the above code is **risky** and not **recommended** as it will put your Joomla site at risk.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming `server.php` to `myfile.php` and see if you still have the same problem. It might be that your Apache server configuration has a rule to block `server.php` because, in many instances, files that have `server.php` as their name are malicious.